# Gsuite Windows Admin and Non-Admin Users

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workspace

I see that you have the option of setting the default account in windows in Google-Workspace Admin as a standard user or a Administrator. I wanted to ask is it possible that if a particular user signs in he gets a local account while another user when he signs in ..signs in as Windows Administrator?

I want to have two Workspace accounts on the windows. One with no admin privileges and other with admin privileges and no local Admin accounts. Only Workspace accounts should be on the system. However, in Google Admin, if I choose standard then ALL the users become standard. That is not what I want. I want to be able to choose. Is this possible?

Comment: Your question is confusing. Are you speaking about Windows Authentication, Google Workspace Authorization, or both? If both, create two separate posts.

Comment: @JohnHanley Hi. Thank You for your response. I was referring to Windows privileges. I figured it out. One has to create separate Organizational Units. Then One can choose which OU's members sign-in as a standard account and which ones as Windows Administrators. Sorry, if the question was confusing.